# Minimum value of A to be able to use envelope detector in amplitude demodulation when m(t) includes an exponential

Tags: analog, communication, modulation, demodulation, amplitude-modulation

[image]

This is one of the exam questions I have come across with. My approach was,

- To be able to get detected by the envelope detector, $$A\geq |\max(m(t))|$$
- Max value of m(t) is 1 right? When t = 0 we get, $$m(0) = \frac{1-0}{e^{0}}u(0) = 1$$
- Therefore, is the minimum value of A = 1?

Comment: your first inequality seems sensible (there's more things you can do to the output of an envelope modulator to be able to reconstruct *overmodulated* signals, i.e. cases where that inequaliy doesn't hold, but that's certainly not subject of this exercise). You want to find the maximum of \$m(t)\$, so do that! (You're right, but you should show it.) Hint: what is the derivative of \$(1-t)e^{-t}\$?

Comment: Okay. Got it. Thank you